# InApp-Browser: Actionbar overlaps WebView content

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, android-actionbar

My problem is that the Actionbar overlaps any webview content like here:

[image]

To compare, it should look like this with the Instagram logo: https://www.instagram.com/about/us/

---

This is my activity_browser.xml of my `InAppBrowser` to open external webview content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".InAppBrowser">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The Actionbar overlaps the webview, so the webview content seems to start where the Actionbar starts.

I tried to wrap `AppBarLayout`, `WebView` and `ProgressBar` inside an additonal `RelativeLayout` but this didn't work either.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I've just added

```
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

to `WebView`, now it *visually* works since I set the margin offset to the same size as the actionbar, but I think this is more of a hacky solution, so I still appreciate other solutions/suggestions.